# How to shift the nextLine text to start from center

Tags: flutter

I am writing an headline so size of text is large so the newline is starting from left but i want it to start from center.

example:
The text is showing like this currently.

```
This is a new
line
```

but,i want to show like this

```
This is a new
    line
```

I am using this code

```
Text("Please Contact us in the morning timings are 10 AM to 12 AM",
   style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `textAlign` property to tell flutter how to align your text horizontally. If you want to horizontally center it, use `textAlign: TextAlign.center,`.

Full example with your widget:

```dart
Text(
  "Please Contact us in the morning timings are 10 AM to 12 AM",
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  the Text() widget inside a Center() widget

`Center( Text("Please Contact us in the morning timings are 10 AM to 12 AM", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,), ) )`